# jquery removeClass not properly working in internet explorer 6

Tags: jquery

i have following navigation,

```
    <ul class="content-nav">
         <li id="nav-liv" class="tab"><a href="index.php?p=recent" page="recent">Recent</a></li>
         <li id="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=friends" page="friends">Friends</a></li>
         <li id="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=following" page="following">Following</a></li>
         <li id="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=my" page="my">My</a></li>
         <li id="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=fav" page="fav">Favourite</a></li>
    <ul>
```

with jquery code

```
    $(".content-nav li#nav-liv a").click(function(){
           $("li#nav-liv").removeClass("tab");
           $(this).parent().addClass("tab");
        return false;
});
```

this is very much working in every browser except ie 6.
In ie 6 when i click on friend link it remove the tab class from recent link, but after clicking others links it doed not removeClass.

Comment: I've never heard of `page` being a valid `a` attribute, did you mean `rel`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, all your `li`s have the ID `#nav-liv`, I guess IE6 is choking on that. The first thing I would do is change them to classes and see if IE6 still has trouble.

Answer (score 1):

ID's should be unique.

```
   <ul class="content-nav">
         <li class="nav-liv tab"><a href="index.php?p=recent" page="recent">Recent</a></li>
         <li class="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=friends" page="friends">Friends</a></li>
         <li class="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=following" page="following">Following</a></li>
         <li class="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=my" page="my">My</a></li>
         <li class="nav-liv"><a href="index.php?p=fav" page="fav">Favourite</a></li>
    <ul>

$(".content-nav li.nav-liv a").click(function(){
       $("li.nav-liv").removeClass("tab");
       $(this).parent().addClass("tab");
    return false;
});
```